# Android Camera throwing error E/Camera: Error 2 on ZxingScannerView.startCamera() in Nougat

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

1. I capture the image using:

   ```
   final Intent cameraIntent = new    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
   ```
2. onActivityResult, I persist the image on the sdcard and then I call the custom dialog box which has ZxingScannerView added in the ViewGroup.

   ```
   final ViewGroup barcodeScanningFrame = (ViewGroup)
   findViewById(R.id.barcodeScanningFrame);
   ZxingScannerView mScannerView = new  ZXingScannerView(activityToDisplayDialogBox.getApplicationContext());
   barcodeScanningFrame.addView(mScannerView);
   mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
   mScannerView.startCamera();
   ```
3. After mScannerView.startCamera(); I get following error

   ```
   E/Camera: Error 2
   E/CameraPreview: java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed
                java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed
                    at   android.hardware.Camera.native_cancelAutoFocus(Native Method)
                    at android.hardware.Camera.cancelAutoFocus(Camera.java:1275)
                    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.stopCameraPreview(CameraPreview.java:109)
                    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.surfaceChanged(CameraPreview.java:61)
                    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:630)
                    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:161)
                    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2205)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   E/CameraPreview: java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
                java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
                    at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
                    at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1896)
                    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.getOptimalPreviewSize(CameraPreview.java:188)
                    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.setupCameraParameters(CameraPreview.java:119)
                    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.showCameraPreview(CameraPreview.java:76)
                    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.surfaceChanged(CameraPreview.java:62)
                    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:630)
                    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:161)
                    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2205)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   ```

It looks like that intent to start the Camera to take the image is not releasing the camera. Because the mScannerView.startCamera() just works fine if I do not do:

```
 final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

and start the custom Dialog box directly:

I have the required permissions and the above code is working fine in marshmallow. Just the nougat devices are throwing me this error in the above mentioned scenario.

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: i got rid of the camera 2 error by disabling the barcode scanner in onPause()